# Most space-efficient way of using rsync to do incremental back up?

Tags: rsync, backup, storage

If we do

```
rsync -a --link-dest=dest1 src dest2
```

Then rsync will only copy files in `src` which have been modified compared to `dest1`. However, even if only one byte in a 1GB file is modified, the entire 1GB will be copied.

How to change the command so that

1. Old versions of the backup are all kept;
2. Only the delta of each file is copied;
3. We can restore any version of any files;
4. We can, in some way, remove the old backups while keeping newer versions?

(This is sort of like snapshots in filesystems like ZFS.)